# Calculating speed of spheres in an asymmetric Newton's cradle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy-conservation, momentum

If we assume there is an asymmetric Newton's cradle with 3 spheres of different masses and the first one is initialized with some certain speed can we calculate the outcome speed of the all the three spheres after the collusion?

I know we can use conservation of linear momentum and kinetic energy to get two different equations but I am having difficulties figuring out how we can solve these equations or reject some of the solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are meant to treat the collisions between spheres 1 and 2 and between spheres 2 and 3 as separate collisions. Solve 1 and 2 first. There will always be a solution where 1 continues with unchanged speed - reject this solution, it would mean that 1 passed through 2 without colliding at all. Then, take your solution for the velocity of 2 and solve the collision between 2 and 3, again rejecting the solution where 2 continues unchanged.

Obviously this sequence-of-collisions treatment is only an approximation. Surprisingly, there is still active research into problems much like this.

Comment: After solving 1 and 2, and then 2 and 3, should I solve 2 and 1 one more time to calculate the final velocities of 1 and 2?

Comment: If your results suggest that there should be another collision: for example if $v_1$ is going forward after the first collision, but $v_2$ goes backwards after its second collision.

Comment: double post, deleted